# How to use phf::map to create new Struct as value?

Tags: rust

I am currently using phf similar to hashmap something like:

```
static MARKETPLACE_MAP: phf::Map<&'static str, &'static str> = phf_map! {
    "Amazon.com" => "Amazon",
    "Google.com" => "Google",
};
```

However how can I initialize this if the value is a struct I want to initialize similar to:

```
static MARKETPLACE_MAP: phf::Map<&'static str, &'static WebsiteInfo> = phf_map! {
    "Amazon.com" => WebsiteInfo::new("Amazon", "USA", "WA", "Seattle"),
    "Google.com" => WebsiteInfo::new("Google", "USA", "CA", "Mountain View")
};
```

What would the syntax be for this?

Comment: If `WebsiteInfo::new` is a `const fn`, the syntax you wrote should work, do you get any errors if you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You have following problem. `calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants` which is explained in [E0015](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0015).

So you'll have to make your `new` function of the struct `WebsiteInfo` a `const fn`, which should work in your case, since it looks like you just need that struct to store some `&str`.

You'll also have to remove the borrow from the `Map` decleration.

`static MARKETPLACE_MAP: phf::Map<&'static str, &'static WebsiteInfo> [...]`

=>

`static MARKETPLACE_MAP: phf::Map<&'static str, WebsiteInfo> [...]`

Since you are storing owned versions of your struct.